# How to use code coverage in PHPStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I've just moved from netbeans to PHPStorm and am trying to come up with a solution for Code Coverage.  I have a personal license only (paid), version 6.0.3.

I would like to know:

- Is it available in this version?  (The documentation says it is available only in the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ IDEA
- How do I configure it?
- Can I still have it generate a code coverage report in html (the way that it does when you run PHPUnit from the command line?)

EDIT: Have answered the third point myself.  (Yes, you can still get the code coverage to generate in html.  The tests have to get through with no fatal errors though).

EDIT #2: OK, so I've answered the first point too - a code coverage option is now available on the bottom right of my screen, after I have run the tests, so that pretty much answers all my queries!

I think I could get to like this PHPStorm...

Comment: Can you please post here how did you generated HTML coverage report? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a documentation on jetbrains web site

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/monitoring-code-coverage-for-php-applications.html